# Accessing protected member of an instance of a superclass

Tags: c++, inheritance

(Edited for completeness)

I have two structures:

```
struct DoubleLinkedList: public LinkedList {
    void push(IntEntry entry) override;
    IntEntry pop(int key) override;
protected:
    DoubleLinkedList *m_previous;
};

struct LinkedList {
    virtual void push(IntEntry entry);
    virtual IntEntry pop(int key);
protected:
    IntEntry m_entry;
    LinkedList* m_next;
};
```

In `IntEntry DoubleLinkedList::pop(int key)` definition, I'm trying to access `m_next->m_entry`, which gives me an error `'m_entry' is a protected member of 'LinkedList'`.

```
IntEntry DoubleLinkedList::pop(int key) {
    if (m_next->m_value.key == key) {
       (...)
    } else {
       (...)
    }
}
```

This is not a problem when accessing `m_next->m_entry` from `IntEntry LinkedList::pop(int key)`.

Is there a way to access a protected member without declaring `DoubleLinkedList` a friend class in `LinkedList` definition? As in, I don't want to `LinkedList` know about `DoubleLinkedList` at all.

Comment: please provide a [mcve].

Comment: When something is `protected` that means you can reach it through `this`, i.e. you can reach your "own" members (even if they are defined in the base class). For other unrelated *objects* you can not access `protected` members.

Comment: somewhere I read about `protected` members being a code smell. I am not sure yet if I agree, but since then I didnt encounter a case where I could not live without `protected` members.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f84ed41adb5d8528)

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm reproducing it (using VS 2010), and I should say that I am very surprised as I would expect this to work.

Comment: @NathanOliver The problem happens for `m_next->m_entry;`.

Comment: I have provided an update with more relevant code. I also expected this to work, since accessing in a similar way is perfectly working from a `LinkedList` instance.

Comment: @songyuanyao Ah, now I see it.

Comment: @Actarus Only the protected members of the current base subobject, which belongs to current object, could be accessed. You can't access protected members of another base class.

Comment: @songyuanyao I was wondering if I haven't broken anything regarding namespacing or anything else or is this actually impossible. Seems to be the latter.

Comment: @bartlomiej.n It seems impossible for current design...Is `m_next` indeed points to an object of `DoubleLinkedList` for this case?

Comment: Based on the comment of @songyuanyao, saying that "Only the protected members of the current base subobject ..." (on which I admit I was not aware), I casted `m_next` to `DoubleLinkedList *` before accessing the member `m_entry` and it works. So in case of `m_next` member of an object of type `DoubleLinkedList` is always of type `DoubleLinkedList *`you can access the m_entry member list this : `static_cast<DoubleLinkedList*>(m_next)->m_entry`.

Comment: @Actarus Yes, it will always be `DoubleLinkedList*`. This seems to do the trick! Thanks! Can't mark this as the answer, so please add this as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already do `static_cast<DoubleLinkedList*>(...m_next)` which is one way to handle it - i.e. `static_cast<DoubleLinkedList*>(m_next)->m_entry`. That cast is a bit dangerous, because if LinkedList inserts a LinkedList element as m_next it will break that cast.

The reason for the problem is that you are mixing implementation (find, Peek) and interface inheritance (push, pop) - it is recommended to not do that:

https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c129-when-designing-a-class-hierarchy-distinguish-between-implementation-inheritance-and-interface-inheritance

Comment: This is a very helpful link, thank you. I'm a beginner to C++ and I'm fairly confused by the sheer amount of language features available.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you start by fixing the first error reported by your compiler, moving on one error at a time. The error I am getting when I try to compile your code is

> 'm_value' : is not a member of 'LinkedList'

on line

```
if (m_next->m_value.key == key)
```

PS. I am getting this error after I had to define a dummy

```
struct IntEntry
{
    static IntEntry empty() { return IntEntry(); };
};
```

If you want more helpful replies please post code that is [complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as others said.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the missing code. I'll update my question.